# Подскажите как реализовать анимацию в html с hover эффектом

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, анимация

Подскажите пожалуйста, требуется реализовать анимацию при наведение на карточку. В какую сторону копать, даже не представляю. Может кто сталкивался с таким и даст напутствие начальное хотя бы)) Буду благодарен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на видео с примером анимации](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/jJ-g8CnNxSzIaA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте поигратся со skew

```css
.item {
  background: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  transform: skew(0, -37deg);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item:hover {
  transform: skew(0, 0);
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```